# Insert and delete checkbox using MySQL and PHP. Use chcekbox like favorites button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use checkbox like favorites button where user can like some articles and then see his favorites articles on web page. And when he no longer likes it, he just unchecks it. Is it possible to do it using PHP, MySQL and JavaScript?

Comment: yes, it is possible  to do it using PHP, MySQL and even without JavaScript

Comment: Of course, this can be realized with HTML, PHP and a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's favorite button using html & css.
if have any query feel free to comment below

```js
$(document).on('change','.cbx',function(){
const liked = Number($(this).is(":checked"));
const id = $(this).closest('.liked-id').val();

  $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "liked.php",
            data: {
                liked:liked,
                id:id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('changed');
            }
        });



});
```

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fbc02d;
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.root label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.root .heart {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease;
}
.root .heart:hover {
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 78, 0.08);
}
.root .heart:active {
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 78, 0.3);
}
.root .heart:active .ripple {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s;
}
.root .heart .checked {
  fill: #dc004e;
  display: none;
}
.root .heart .unchecked {
  fill: grey;
}
.root .cbx {
  display: none;
}
.root .cbx:checked + label .checked {
  display: inline;
}
.root .cbx:checked + label .unchecked {
  display: none;
}
.root .ripple {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 78, 0.8);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
 <input  type="text" class="liked-id" hidden value="<?php echo $liked_id ?? '' ?>" />
 <input id="cbx" class="cbx" type="checkbox" />
 <label for="cbx">
            <span class="heart">
                <span class="ripple"></span>
                <svg class="unchecked" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28 22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5 5.5 5 7.5 5c1.54 0 3.04.99 3.57 2.36h1.87C13.46 5.99 14.96 5 16.5 5c2 0 3.5 1.5 3.5 3.5 0 2.89-3.14 5.74-7.9 10.05z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
                <svg class="checked" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </label>
</div>
```

**liked.php**

```php
if($_POST["liked"]){
// insert logic here
}else{
// delete logic here using $_POST["id"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it is hard to give you a proper answer, what you need to do is use checked as conditional for the field and use ajax call to trigger your PHP here is one of the many ways to trigger your php script to call the DB after

```
<input type="checkbox" class="articleCheckbox" onclick="removeLike()" name="articlecyz" value="like" <? if isset($liked) echo 'checked' ?> >

<script>
function removeLike() {

   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.querySelector('.articleCheckbox').checked; = this.responseText;
       }
     };

   xhttp.open("POST", "where-your-form-points-at.php", true);
   xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have any checkbox code yet. I only have database with 3 rows: id_fav, article_id and id_user

Comment: Ok well start by creating a form that will work with php and your database to check and uncheck. the JavaScript part is secondary.